# Behavior of optional word matches in the regex '^(al |ali |alia |alias ) '

Tags: regex, regex-group

How can I optionally match one of the following words at the beginning of a line? `al` or `ali` or `alia` or `alias`.

I've tried the optional syntax shown in the title but no luck. Several SO questions stated that that's only what's needed, however this is the result I get when testing the pattern with nodejs:

```js
> const ac = new RegExp('^(al |ali |alia |alias )', 'g');
undefined
> ac.test('al ')
true
> ac.test('ali ')
false
> ac.test('alia ')
true
> ac.test('alias ')
false
```

As you can see, there's an alternating pattern of true/false that I found absolutely confusing.
As an example, test for 'ali ' failed, however in a simple online test engine you can see that it passes:

[image]

What am I missing??

Comment: I ran your code in my browser and it works as expected

Comment: I'm trying the same exact code (copypasted) that I wrote, both in the browser console and in nodejs shell on the terminal. I'm getting the same result in both of them. true/false/true/false

Comment: Could you share with me what exactly you ran in your browser?

Comment: @Sweeper yep, that was it. Thank you